# Creating a button leads to image array

Tags: ios, xcode, arrays, uiscrollview, paging

I've followed this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/10518/how-to-use-uiscrollview-to-scroll-and-zoom-content) for Paging with UIScrollView and it has some arrays with images.
and I want to create a button which takes me to image array that I've chosen (To clarify : When I tap on the button it takes me to photo3.png).
Please review the tutorial first in order to understand what I mean.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You're basically saying - "Please go and read Tutorial X and then come back here and explain it to me".

Comment: Sorry, Being beginner is my problem !!

Comment: I appreciate you are a beginner, but you can't create applications by blindly following a tutorial and then coming on to Stack Overflow to have fix the bits you don't understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using the following task of [UIScrollView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html)?

`- (void)scrollRectToVisible:(CGRect)rect animated:(BOOL)animated`

You simply pass a `CGRect` matching the `frame` of the page you would like to display.

**EDIT added code**

```
-(IBAction)scrollToPageNumberFive:(id)sender {
  int scrollToPage = 5; //just an example
  int scrollToX = 5-1; //because X starts from 0
  [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(scrollToX*self.scrollView.frame.size.width,0,self.scrollView.frame.size.width,self.scrollView.frame.size.height) animated:YES];
}
```

Calling the `scrollRectToVisible:animated:` will call the `scrollViewDidScroll:` method from the tutorial that will load and purge appropriate pages.

Comment: Actually I followed the tutorial above only .. What I need to do is very simple .. I just want the button to take me to a photo in the arrays of the UIScrollVIew .. Have you got it ? And do you have any ideas about that ?

Comment: I use the above method for that in my projects. Let's say that I have 10 objects in the scroll view and I want to get to number 4. Each page has a size 100 by 100, y=0 and first page has x=0. And then you could use: [myScrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(100*(4-1),0,100,100) animated:YES]

Comment: but I don't want to change my whole project just to add this feature .. anyway thank you for your time :)

Comment: You don't have to change anything. In the tutorial there is a part of the code that sets frames for each page and adds them to UIScrollView. You need to use the same frames. And you simply trigger the method I suggest in an IBAction.

Comment: Oh, yes I got it :D it seems to be right :) .. But I'm beginner in iOS Development and I have created that scrollView by following the tutorial and I can't understand all codes in it ! .. You're saying that you have made something similar to it before .. Can you just PLEASE show me that code .. Let's say I need to go to image number 5 show me how you did this please :) I've voted up the answer and I will accept it immediately but please show me that .. Thanks!

Comment: It is like I wrote in my first comment. But here we go again:) Say you want to go to page 5. It is nice to store all your pages in an array, i.e. pagesArray (I use NSMutableArray to which I add pages objects in a for loop that also adds pages to the scroll view by addSubview method) or you can even just store their x coordinate. You have a button that triggers an IBAction, right? The IBAction should call the following '[myScrollView scrollRectToVisible:[pagesArray objectAtIndex:4].frame animated:YES]'. If you are still in trouble, I will post a whole example.

Comment: Please post the whole example .. I'm still in trouble .. thank you :)